# Uploading Volatile Table using VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, teradata, volatile

I have a local table in an MS Access 2010 database. I would like to use ADODB to load the local table into a Teradata environment within my spool space using CREATE VOLATILE TABLE command

This should be achievable i think using arrays but i was wondering is there a better way (speedy too if possible) to batch load the records into the teradata environment for example

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE EXAMPLE AS (SELECT * FROM LOCAL TABLE)
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX(Set Index Keys)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Thanks for your help

**Just a quick update on this [24/01/2013]**

I have managed to get the data from the access database, Load it into an Array, Create a Volatile table in my teradata warehouse using spool space and then attempt to load the array into the table

I am getting the error: TEMP_TABLE already exists. when trying to append the records to the table

I am almost there so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you again for your help

```
Public Function Open_Connection()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' http://voices.yahoo.com/teradata-ms-excel-vba-2687156.html
    ' The connection is used to connect with the DBMS,
    ' The Recordset to surf the result of some SELECT queries
    ' The Command to send the sql requests to Teradata.

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmdSQLData As ADODB.Command
Set cmdSQLData = New ADODB.Command
Dim myArray() As Variant

' Open Connection With Teradata
cn.Open "Data Source=Database; " & _
        "Database=Database; " & _
        "Persist Security Info=True; " & _
        "User ID=Me; " & _
        "Password=FakePassword; " & _
        "Session Mode=ANSI;"

' Which database it has to send the query
Set cmdSQLData.ActiveConnection = cn

   ' Query to create the violotile table in Teradata'
       Query = "CREATE VOLATILE TABLE TEMP_TABLE ( " & _
            "field1 VARCHAR (39)," & _
            "field2 VARCHAR (44)," & _
            "field3 DECIMAL (18, 3)," & _
            "field4 CHAR (3))" & _
            "ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;"

' Query is assessed as Text
cmdSQLData.CommandText = Query
' Specifies which kind of command VBA has to execute
cmdSQLData.CommandType = adCmdText
' Remove Query Timeouts
cmdSQLData.CommandTimeout = 60
'VBA just run the query and send back the result
Set rs = cmdSQLData.Execute()

' Retrieve the sharepoint records into an Array
myArray = Retrieve_Sharepoint_Records

intNumberRows = UBound(myArray, 2) + 1 ' number of records/rows in the array
rowcounter = 0

' Append the Rows to the temp table
For rowcounter = 0 To intNumberRows - 1
        ' Debug.Print myArray(0, rowcounter) & " | " & myArray(1, rowcounter) & " | " & myArray(2, rowcounter) & " | " & myArray(3, rowcounter)
    AppendQuery = "INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE VALUES ('" & myArray(0, rowcounter) & "','" & myArray(1, rowcounter) & "'," & myArray(2, rowcounter) & ",'" & myArray(3, rowcounter) & "');"

    cmdSQLData.CommandText = Query
    cmdSQLData.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmdSQLData.CommandTimeout = 60
    Set rs = cmdSQLData.Execute()

Next

' Clean up
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Set cmdSQLData = Nothing

ErrorHandler:
If (Len(Err.Description) > 0) Then
    MsgBox (Err.Description)
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Can you link tables with ODBC http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/odbc-driver/windows ?

Comment: Hi Remou, I can link permanent tables but a volatile table exists within the spool space of the user. Once the query disconnects the table disappears. It isn't possible as far as i can see

Comment: Just guessing here, but you might be able to use a passthrough query and something equivalent to OPENROWSET http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/95353ff8-2605-4b21-9dee-1a3a8b18f556/connecting-from-sql-server-to-teradata-with-openrowset-without-linked-server

Answer (score 0):

You may have better success using a `Global Temporary Table` as the object definition is stored within the `DBC` Data Dictionary on Teradata. The population of the table is session specific using the `TEMPORARY` space assigned to the user or the profile of the user.

Comment: Hi Rob, I have to use the temporary space as its a global network decision

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my own question, I should change the second code line of below

```
cmdSQLData.CommandText = Query
```

To

```
cmdSQLData.CommandText = AppendQuery
```

It then works perfectly albeit slowly

Again thank you all for your help

Comment: You didn't specify a Primary Index for your table, this might be one reason why it's slow. How many rows will be loaded?

Comment: Sorry, got side tracked with another project. I have specified the primary index for the table and now its running on production data (I took a sample). It is 60,000 + records a week. Inserting the records one at a time is incredibly slow. Is there a way to batch upload the records like 1000 at a time

Comment: I don't know how to do this in Access, but you might try #1: prepared SQL, passing the data using parameters #2: multiple sessions or #3: multistatements, i.e. multiple INSERTs in a single CommandText each terminated by a semicolon (up to the maximum size of a query = 1MB)

Comment: Is it possible to open up multiple connections into the DB in a volatile session? The multiple inserts might be a way of looking at it too...I hadnt thought of that

Comment: Multiple session will not work for Volatile Tables, because VTs are session local, so multistatements should be the fastest way.